# Firebase Simple Login and Twitter API access

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, firebase

I am trying to authenticate user by twitter oAuth and firebase simple login plugin (https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html). Authentication and login works perfectly but the problems came when i try to get access to twitter API after this. I wish to get some tweets from twitter but all of my requests have the same response that `XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json` from my domain, localhost or firebase...

I am trying with jQuery method `$.get`, also with `$.getJSON`

```
$.getJSON("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%23stackoverflow", {},
    function (data) {
        console.log(data);
);
```

In callback URL in twitter application settings i've add each posible url: domain, localhost, and firebase callback url. Anybody know this problem, anybody was trying to get tweets using firebase and firebase simple login, anybody can help? Much thx from the top.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Simple Login has been deprecated.

You should set up your Twitter Application if you haven't done so.

[Firebase Walkthrough](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/twitter.html)

This will walk you step by step to allow users to be authenticated with Twitter.